# Render not coming out as expected

Tags: rendering

I'm making fan art for a youtube channel I watch and When I click Shift-Z, to see the preview render, it shows itself as nice and smooth
[image]

but when I render it, it doesn't come out as smooth
[image]

If you look closely you'll see what I'm talking about. Any suggestions on what could be causing this. Camera is in Orthographic.

Comment: Why did you mark it as a duplicate of a question that was also a duplicate? XD Hehe just giving you a hard time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps change the render settings to 100% under 'Dimensions.' The default is set to 50% which makes it half the size for some reason.